# Algorithm for checking whether a set of hyperplanes covers $\mathbb{Z}_r^n$

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

In what follows, $r \in \mathbb{N}$ is not necessarily prime. $\mathbb{Z}_r$ is shorthand for $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$.

Given a set of $h$ hyperplanes $A \vec x = b \mod r$, we can check whether the union of the hyperplanes equals the entirety of $\mathbb{Z}_r^n$ in $O(r^n \text{poly}(r,n,h))$ time by just plugging in all $r^n$ points and checking whether each point is on at least one hyperplane. Is there a faster algorithm?

Comment: Probably not by much; it should be NP-hard, from the NP-hardness of checking whether the union of a set of arithmetic progressions equals Z.

Comment: @BernardoSubercaseaux, that sounds like an answer!  Can I encourage you to write that in the 'Your Answer' box instead of as a comment, so we can upvote it and the question will be considered answered?  There probably isn't any need to elaborate, even a concise answer is still an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong; I didn't realize in this problem $r$ is the same for all hyperplanes. It follows from [Theorem 6.1 here][1] that the problem of deciding whether a set of arithmetic progressions $\{a_i + n \cdot b_i \; \vert \; n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ has their union equal to $\mathbb{Z}$ is NP-hard. 

However, in this case $r$ is the same for all hyperplanes, which could make it easier. On the flip side, this problem is over $Z^n$, which is another source of difficulty... I tried to think of a reduction, but didn't succeed. 

  [1]: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/800125.804029